Magento 2: How to add <img> tag with product image inside product cart added success message
I need to show a message of the added product inside cart in Magento 2.
I override addCartSuccessMessage phtml correctly but i can't add an <img> tag inside this phtml file because it disapear.
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<div class="addCartSuccessMessaheHidden">
    <img src="productImageUrl" />
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
        'You added %1 to your <a href="%2">shopping cart</a>.',
        $block->getData('product_name'),
        $block->getData('cart_url')
    ), ['a']);
    ?>
</div>

What i need is something like this, after the user add a product in cart:

Thanks!!
I try to add an img tag, i try to add a popup using js...

You can add img tag in add to cart msg by following below steps
Open Controller file Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
in else add this code i used object manager, don't
else {
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
                    $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
                    $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                        'addCartSuccessMessage',
                        [
                            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                            'product_image' => $imageUrl,
                            'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                            
                        ]
                    );
                }
Above code to get img url

2nd step
in addCartSuccessMessage.phtml file
use this code
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added %1 to your <a href="%2">shopping cart</a> and %3',
    $block->getData('product_name'),

    $block->getData('cart_url'),
    $block->getData('product_image')

), ['a']); ?>

3rd step
in /magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
update this function prepareMessageForHtml function with this
prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            console.log('prepareMessageForHtmlss');
            console.log(message);
            const splitMessage = message.split(' and ');
            const cartItem = splitMessage[0];
            const imageUrl = splitMessage[1];
            console.log('Cart Item:', cartItem);
            console.log('Image URL:', imageUrl);
            return escaper.escapeHtml(cartItem, this.allowedTags) + '<img src="' + imageUrl + '">';
        }

result will be like that
enter image description here

if you need to add popup i can help you with that, too.
